# Java Maven project in VSCode: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, gradle

Full disclaimer: **I'm not a Java expert**.

My work group developed a Java project, managed by maven, which should be compiled against jdk-11. They all use IntelliJ and I was able to set it up on this platform. I'm now trying to do the same setup on VSCode, because I'm more familiar with it.

I installed openjdk-11, added the relevant `cacerts` in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security`, pointed VSCode to this version and to the same maven executable used by IntelliJ for compiling.

I can correctly compile the project by doing `mvn clean install` and run part of the application in the Run/Debug window (only had to manually add all the `classPaths` in `launch.json`). However the "Language Support for Java" tab in the Output window still shows me this error

```
Cannot download published Gradle versions.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Cannot download published Gradle versions.
....
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...
[Error - 10:18:41] 27 Feb 2023, 10:18:41 Error occured while building workspace. Details: 
 message: The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved;
```

It seems that the "Language Support for Java" is using a different jdk with no cacerts installed, but somehow I cannot figure out where this version is located. I tried to specify the right `java_home` wherever I could in VSCode (also in Gradle) but somehow I cannot get rid of this error.
I don't know if this is really a problem or not, as the project is compiling when I launch maven, but it would be good to fix it. To me it is not really clear at the moment how many different "layers" are used when opening a java project like this in VSCode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

Trying to resolve this problem for my environment, I found your comment

> It seems that the "Language Support for Java" (VSCode plugin) is using a different jdk ...

was the key to discovering a fix in my case.
[This link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2259) explains that the extension does use an embedded JRE and also provides a resolution to the problem.

The embedded JRE is located at (depending on extension version and operating system):

```
.vscode/extensions/redhat.java-1.15.0-linux-x64/jre
```

which is usually located directly under `$HOME` on Linux and MacOS or `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows. The embedded JRE has a `cacerts` file, for example:

```
.vscode/extensions/redhat.java-1.15.0-linux-x64/jre/17.0.6-linux-x86_64/lib/security/cacerts
```

To resolve the problem you can either:

1. add the required certificates to the embedded JRE `cacerts` file, *however, you will need to repeat this every time the extension is updated*, or
2. configure the embedded JRE to use another certificate store file that contains the required certificates by modifying the VSCode user settings (`settings.xml` file) `"java.jdt.ls.vmargs"` entry to *append* the properties:

   ```
   "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/other/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
   ```

   substituting the correct certificate store path and password.

In the case of option 2 you can simply use the path to the Open JDK 11 `cacerts` file that you have already modified.

Comment: Thanks! that clarifies a lot. But unfortunately I tried both options and I'm still getting the error :(

Comment: Thanks! for me first option worked. I was using remote-development with Java project. After doing following steps, PKIX errors with pom.xml went away,
```
# Set JAVA_HOME to path of your VSCode JRE
export JAVA_HOME=~/.vscode-server/extensions/redhat.java-1.25.0/jre/17.0.9-linux-x86_64/
# Import certs
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias mycert -file ~/certs/certificate.crt -cacerts
```

Answer (score 0):

For me first option from above answer worked. I was using VS Code Remote Development with Java project. After doing following steps, PKIX errors with pom.xml went away,

```
# Set JAVA_HOME to path of your VSCode JRE
export JAVA_HOME=~/.vscode-server/extensions/redhat.java-1.25.0/jre/17.0.9-linux-x86_64/
# Import certs
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias mycert -file ~/certs/certificate.crt -cacerts
```

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Use-proper-cacerts-to-import-Java-projects also helps.

Answer (score -2):

Starting with Maven 3.9 they changed the default Transport implementation to **native**.

Try with this option to disable SSL verifications:

```
mvn compile -Daether.connector.https.securityMode=insecure
```

Background:
https://maven.apache.org/resolver/configuration.html

Comment: Poster specifically mentioned they can correctly compile via maven.  Their question is focused on the Java language support provided by a VSCode extension.  This answer does not apply to that.